# background-image in body:before on IE not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer

I have created a webdesign with used body:before tag to 'split' the design, similar to the TwentyFifteen theme of WordPress (https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyfifteen/)

But I don't use a color for the "left" column, but an image. The Code works in all browsers fine (Chrome, FF, Safari) but not in IE (Version 9-11).

The CSS looks like:

```
body::before {
    background: url("img/back-left.jpg") no-repeat center top ;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 30%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The effect: the background picture was not showing, when open the page with IE. When I go to a sub-site, the picture was showing. When I transform the browser windows, the picture was showing. When I change ANYTHING (no matter what) in IE Dev toolbar, the picture was showing.

If I use background-color instead of background (or background-image), it works fine on IE.

Any ideas? I think it sounds like a rendering thing. The background image was rendered too late and so was not showing (instead I interact everthing on the page). But how to fix it?

Comment: "left" column meaning the sidebar?

Comment: Yes, this means the sidebar. On the TwentyFifteen the area with de menu links.

Comment: instead of using the `body:before`, why not just use the `sidebar` elements that's already in place?

Comment: I don't use the TwentyFifteen theme. I write a custom theme. It just looks similar. And I need a fullscreen background image ofer the body:before.

Comment: Correcting: Problem just occurs on IE10 and IE11. IE9 displays it correct.

Comment: try using relative path  - ie `/img/back-left.jpg`. try putting a space in b/w the double quotes - ie `content: " ";`. try using `:before` rather than `::before` - sorry just trying options. also try changing width to a set width rather than percentage. perhaps since you've put it on the `body` element it doesn't know the width yet on initial page load on IE

Comment: I tried just several things, and found the error, but not solution yet. The problem seems to be the Scrollbar. As soon as the scrollbar in IE apears, the background-image was not showing. I create an example in CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEwEVy -> When loading in IE, and you have no Scrollbar in bottom "Content" side. The background in "Navigation" side is showing. When you make the windows smaller, and reload the site: as soon as the scrollbar apears, the background is not showing, expect you rezise the window a little bit. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found a 'solution', that run into an other problem. ;-)

When I set

```
html, body { overflow: auto; }
```

Then, the background-image was displayed proper in IE 10 and IE 11. But now I have the IE 11 smooth scrolling problem (The background image jump all over the place when using the mouse wheel. When using the scrollbar, it works fine).
Anyway, this variant is better for me, than not displaying the background-image. So I still hoping, that MS correct the smooth-scrolling bug.

I made a fork in CodePen with this correction: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rabMMm

(this was the originally CodePen code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEwEVy)

Or did any knows a solution to fix the smooth scrolling prolem from IE?