# Absolute background on pseudo-element ::before on IE 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

My problem is pretty weird. I have a background in a `container::before`, absolute-positioned and on every browser it works perfectly.

On IE 11 when I first load my page, my background only takes the width of my container (both sides are not visible).  When I open my debugger or when I move the window the sides are revealed.

I tried [this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368908/background-image-in-bodybefore-on-ie-not-working) but it doesn't work.

```
.connexion-layout {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden; 
}
.connexion-layout .container {
    padding-top: 200px;
    padding-bottom: 200px; 
}

.connexion-layout .container::before {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    background: none no-repeat center center / cover; 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
    .connexion-layout .container::before {
        background-image: url("../../theme/images/connexion-bg-desktop.jpg?1433411383"); 
    } 
}
@media screen and (max-width: 979px) {
    .connexion-layout .container::before {
        background-image: url("../../theme/images/connexion-bg-mobile.jpg?1433411383"); 
    } 
}
```

Have you ever had something like this?

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, only post the compiled CSS.

Comment: Have you found an answer? I have the exact same thing!

Comment: You always need positioning, other than static, set on the parent or else it will use the first element that has, until body reached. Normally one use ` position: relative;`

Answer (score 1):

Adding `position: relative;` to the parent fixed this exact same bug for me.

Comment: Haha. I should have looked closer at the code. I'm going to be so mad if that really was the issue. What confuses me is why it corrects itself on repaint. One would think that would be an issue across browsers...

Comment: I know right, I really think this error is IE related and not an intended behaviour, especially that it repaints when I just yell at it!

Comment: @MikeGleasonjrCouturier This seems to have fixed a problem I had with using multiple CSS backgrounds in pseudo-elements (some of the images would not show up until I resized the window), where the pseudo-elements had `position: fixed;`.  Thanks.

Comment: @MikeGleasonjrCouturier Actually, I guess I'd say this "partially fixed" my problem... it make the images show up right away.   But the "scrolling flicker" problem that is well-known for fixed background images in IE11 is now happening.

Comment: In my case, the bg image didn't display at all; I googled and was brought to this page. But I was able to fix: In case someone had this issue and adding `position: relative` on the parent didn't work - I only had the `right` property set. Once I also specified `left`, my bg image displayed as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "it corrects itself when I resize the window or open the console" you are actually saying "forcing a browser repaint".

I haven't encountered this exact issue, but I did have a similar one with webfonts in Chrome a while back. It had to do with the order of loading.

So, based on that information, I'm going to guess that because the browser renders things in order, it's rendering the :before element first, then the parent element. However, the :before element's position is based upon the parent element (which it hasn't loaded yet) so it goes to the next available positioned element. When you resize, everything is loaded so it's fine.

There are two things I would try.

First, if you can, move it to the :after element. That may fix it. Since it is absolutely positioned, the :before vs :after shouldn't matter.

If that isn't possible, you can use a javascript/jquery repaint hack.

```
if($('html').hasClass('ie11')) {
  $('.connexion-layout').hide(0, function(){$(this).show()});
}
```

Alternatively, you can try this in CSS. Load it at the bottom of your CSS. Again, this was meant for fonts but it should force a repaint regardless:

```
.ie11 body {
  animation-duration: 0.1s;
  animation-name: repaint;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes repaint {
  from { opacity: 1; }
  to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Both the jquery and css assume you have a classname of ie11 on your `<html>` so that you don't unnecessarily repaint other browsers.

I don't have a PC at the moment, so please let me know if none of these work and I'll find my BrowserStack login and give it a whirl.